# sed search and replace problem

Tags: sed, find, replace

I am trying to replace a string from a file which contains '&' in its value.

```
vari = '111|abc & efg|123'
varj = '222|abc & efg|123'

echo $vari | sed -e "s/$vari/$varj/g"
```

output is `222|abc 111|abc & efg|123 efg|123`

I don't know how to handle '&' in find and replace variable. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just to add that i am doing this in korn shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` character in `$varj` has a special meaning in the replace portion of an `s/search/replace/` command.  It means "insert the matching text here".

You can use `\&` to 'escape' the `&` so it doesn't have a special meaning.  You can use sed to modify `$varj` to replace all `&` chars with `\&`:

```
varj=$(echo "$varj" | sed -e 's/\&/\\\&/g')
```

For example:

```
cas@ganesh:/tmp$ ksh
$ vari='111|abc & efg|123'
$ varj='222|abc & efg|123'

$ echo "$vari" | sed -e "s/$vari/$varj/g"
222|abc 111|abc & efg|123 efg|123

$ varj=$(echo "$varj" | sed -e 's/\&/\\\&/g')
$ echo "$varj"
222|abc \& efg|123

$ echo "$vari" | sed -e "s/$vari/$varj/g"
222|abc & efg|123
```

Comment: super stuff. Worked

Comment: Or (with _{ba,k,z}sh_) simply: `sed "s#${vari}#${varj//&/\\&}#g"`

Answer (score 0):

You need escape the `&` character in the replacement text. This is because `&` is a special character for the replacement text. So let your `$varj` be as follows.

```
varj = '222|abc \& efg|123'
```

You can then call `sed` as follows.

```
echo $vari | sed -e "s/$vari/$varj/g"
```

Comment: vari is a line from a file and i am not able to substitute anything in this line because of '&'

Comment: @girishchalke no, it is not because of the `&`. Just insert the \ as shown in the answer and it will work.

Comment: this problem has nothing to do with spaces.  even if it did, the correct way to deal with it would be to use double-quotes whenever using (e.g. echo-ing) $vari or $varj.  e.g. `echo "$vari" | sed ...`. In fact, as a general rule it is almost always best to use double-quotes around variables except in the very few instances where you know precisely why you don't want to use quotes.

Comment: @tchem. Tried your recommendations but still no success.  Just to ensure its not because of '&', i removed it and kept space as it is.  vari="111|abc efg |123"; echo $vari |sed -e "s/$vari/$varj/g"  This worked which suggests problem is with '&'